# Does Braintree work with magento2 for automated recurring billing?

Tags: magento2, billing

Does Braintree work with magento2 for automated recurring billing? Or is authorize.net our only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 does not have any kind of recurring billing solution built-in. Magento1 had recurring profiles, but that functionality was dropped in M2.

At present, there are two third-party extensions (that I'm aware of) offering this kind of functionality for M2:

1. Magenest's [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments](http://store.magenest.com/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-magento-2.html)
2. ParadoxLabs' [Adaptive Subscriptions](https://store.paradoxlabs.com/magento2-subscriptions-recurring-billing.html)

Full disclosure: I wrote the ParadoxLabs module. I can't speak to Magenest's solution in terms of quality or what payment methods it might support. Adaptive Subscriptions is the only one audited and available on the Magento Marketplace.

The ParadoxLabs module only supports Authorize.Net as of this writing (as you may be aware), but we have support for Braintree and PayPal PayFlow Pro well underway, and others planned. Please contact us directly if you'd like to know more or discuss this further.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, One more question as we want to use Paradox and are about to install authorize.net. 

We use Netsuite. Do you know if NetSuite supports authorize.net?
Do you know if they expose transaction details in order API? 

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with NetSuite before personally, but Magento does expose transaction details via the official API. Depends on what exactly NetSuite requires. I think I saw an email from you about this; we'll respond, if we haven't already.